# PyDev Eclipse - using shelve works despite import unresolved

Tags: python-3.x, pydev, shelve

I am using eclipse pydev for my python project and I have a module where I use shelve. The import of shelve is marked as unresolved in the editor but the programs runs correctly.
When I comment the import it no longer works.

How comes the shelve module is working despite unresolved import?

I signal I use python from a virtual env

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your PYTHONPATH is not properly adding the lib folder where shelve is defined within Eclipse/PyDev.

To check it do the following: create a program with:

```
import shelve
import os
print(os.path.dirname(shelve.__file__))
```

Run it and then check in the interpreter configuration (in the interpreter preferences) if that folder is actually added there.

Comment: Thank you. It print /usr/lib64/python3.6. In fact as I created a virtual environment I thought that I could have a shelve module in it and removed the /usr/lib64/python3.6.  How to have shelve in the virtual env?

Comment: Have you added ` /usr/lib64/python3.6` to the virtual env `Python Interpreter` in the related preferences page?